# Unable to Scroll down a dialog and double click the folder

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dialog

Requirement is to double click a folder name in this dialog. As the folder is not visible to double click, we should scroll down to get the folder and double click as it is available down(folders are in alphabetical order in this dialog). Scroll down using JS Executor is not working.

How to scroll down this dialog and double click the folder? Without scrolling down the folder is not visible to click.

Folder name: Demos business Story

html:

```
<span class="CatalogObjectListListViewItem" title="Demos Business Story" tabindex="0">
<img class="CatalogObjectListItemSmallIcon" src="/analytics/res/v-eBAAmeYhUME/sk_Alta/catalog/folder.png" alt="Folder">
<span>Demos Business Story</span></span>

xpath used in code:
//span[contains(@class, 'CatalogObjectListListViewItem') and (@title='%1')]
```

Am not understanding how %1 detects the folder name in this xpath.

Tried:
`((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");`  //scroll down the dialog
`doubleClick("elemSaveDialogListViewItem" + "(" + folder + ")");` //double click on the folder

Answer (score 1):

To click on `Demos Business Story` Induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable()` and following locator.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='CatalogObjectListListViewItem']/span[text()='Demos Business Story']"))).click();
```

OR click on the image tag.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='CatalogObjectListListViewItem']/img[@class='CatalogObjectListItemSmallIcon']"))).click();
```

---

Not sure if you need to click on twice or not.However you can use action class to do doubleclick()

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement clcikelm=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='CatalogObjectListListViewItem']/span[text()='Demos Business Story']")));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(clcikelm).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: Will above code would scroll down the dialog and click?